# VC++ debugger - evaluating a virtual function, CXX0052: Error: member function not present

Tags: c++, debugging, inheritance, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Shapes {circle, rectangle};

class Shape {
public:
  virtual Shapes getType() const = 0;
};
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
  Shapes getType() const {
    return circle;
  }
};
class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
  Shapes getType() const {
    return rectangle;
  }
};
int main() {
  Shape *sPtr = new Circle;
  cout << "Circle type: " << sPtr->getType() << endl;
  sPtr = new Rectangle;
  cout << "Rectangle type: " << sPtr->getType() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I tried to use debugger to watch sPtr->getType(), it says CXX0052: Error: member function not present. What's wrong here?

Comment: Unfortunately your simplified version compiles and runs fine (at least on gcc 4.7.2). It seems you lost the problem somewhere.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No it's a just debugger issue ("*VC++ debugger*" / "*When I tried to watch*"). The debugger yields that error not the compiler nor the code itself. Granted the wording of the question could be improved.

Comment: I assume compiler optimized your code and dropped functions (while they are virtual, it is clear, what type of objects are used in particular call

Comment: thanks syam, wording updated.

Comment: @user14042: Nothing's wrong with your code, but obviously something's wrong with your debugger. Are you compiling in Debug (as opposed to Release) mode? If you *are* compiling in Debug mode then I guess it's just a bug (ironically, some debuggers are full of bugs).

Comment: yes, it is in debug mode. I am using VC++ 2008.

Comment: Well, a sad (but unavoidable) fact is that C++ toolchains also have bugs. If you can't upgrade to a newer version where this bug is fixed there's only one solution: live with it (I've had my share of crappy toolchains, it's frustrating but there's little one can do). A workaround would be to use an intermediary variable and watch that variable instead of the call itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here [Expression Evaluator Error CXX0052](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d5xy7s9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for the explanation as to why you get this error when you tried to watch it on the debugger.

Visual Studio property to edit to turn off inline function expansion:

[image]

Change the "Inline function expansion" from "Default" to "Disabled (/Ob0)".

Comment: thanks, but how do I do this "Recompile the file with inlining forced off (/Ob0) to set a breakpoint in this function." ?

Comment: Right click on the project name and select "Properties". It will pop-up a dialog. In there expand, "Configuration Properties". Then go to "C/C++ > Optimization". On the right side click on the line that says "Inline Function Expansion". Usually it will say "Default". If you click it will show a drop down and in there you select the option that has the "/Ob0" option.

Answer (score 1):

Only small subset of simple functions can be called by Debugger. Functions from your example are considered to be too complex.

Also, check this topic: [invoking functions while debugging with Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271042/invoking-functions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio-2005)

For example, this:

```
enum Shapes {circle, rectangle};

class Circle {
public:
  Shapes getType() const
  {
    return circle;
  }
};

int main() {
  Circle *sPtr1 = new Circle;
  auto t = sPtr1->getType();
  return 0;
}
```

works fine in QuickWatch.